# Let $x = \mathrm{asec}\,(\theta)$ in $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$. Find $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Let $x = a \sec\,(\theta)$ in $\sqrt{x^2-a^2}$.

If $a>0$ and $0 < \theta < \pi/2$, then find $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: thanks so much shaun :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x=a \sec \theta$ then $\cos \theta = a/x$ and $\sin \theta = \sqrt{1-a^2/x^2}$ since for $0 < \theta < \pi /2$ we have $\sin \theta = \sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta}$.

Comment: Can you explain a little further on how you got sin? Thanks a ton in advance bwv you don't know how much this means to me.

Comment: @Bill Are you aware of the identity $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$? It is essentially the Pythagorean theorem (draw a right triangle with unit hypotenuse). Rearranging you get (in general) $\sin \theta = \pm \sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta}$. Since we know $\sin \theta$ is positive on $0 < \theta < \pi/2$, one has $\sin \theta = +\sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta}$. Now substitute $\cos \theta = a/x$.

Comment: I wasn't, thank you so much for your help.